# R into C++: Rcpp - Combinatorial example

Tags: c++, r, combinations, rcpp

I have this computational expensive example. And i want to turn into compiled code using Rcpp (c++).

```
# Data frame 5 columns / 20 rows
a<-data.frame(A=rnorm(20),B=rnorm(20),C=rnorm(20),D=rnorm(20))

# Combinations of 2 slots of the columns names
b<- t(combn(names(a),2))

# create a list where each element has the names of the columns combination as a vector
c<-lapply(1:nrow(b),function(y) {as.vector(b[y,])})

# Resulting new data.frame where each column is the mean of the columns in the original data frame
# that are a particular combination
d<-as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(c),function(x) {apply(a[,unlist(c[x])],1,mean)})))
```

Any advice on how to do it. I find really complicated to set the matrix before hand in C++ when the number of elements in the set (N) and the number of subsets change (K).

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurring to the `C` or `C++` should be the last resource to speed up a code. I guess a good practice it's to try to do better in R. Your code is very inefficient from an R perspective and I suggest the following way which should speed up things a little. Note: it's almost sure that a `C(++)` solution would be still (much) faster, but maybe you'll be happy with this. Try:

```
#you can obtain the `c` object of your example simply like this.
c<-combn(names(a),2,simplify=FALSE)
res<-vapply(c,function(x) rowMeans(a[x]),numeric(nrow(a)))
```

You'll end up with a `matrix` that you can coerce to a `data.frame` to obtain `d`. Also notice that you should keep the result as `matrix`, if every column is `numeric`. `data.frame` should be used if each column can be of a different kind. Some benchmarks:

```
set.seed(1)
a<-data.frame(A=rnorm(200000),B=rnorm(200000),C=rnorm(200000),D=rnorm(200000))
system.time(x<-do.call(cbind,lapply(1:length(c),function(x) {apply(a[,unlist(c[x])],1,mean)})))
# user  system elapsed 
#7.612   0.036   7.655  
system.time(x1<-vapply(c,function(x) rowMeans(a[x]),numeric(nrow(a))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.02
all.equal(x,x1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Thanks to @user20650 for the very elegant solution:

```
combn(a, 2, simplify=T, rowMeans)
```

The above is a little slower than the `vapply` one since I guess it take a little time to reorganize the result in a matrix.

Comment: Thanks to both for the answer. Amazing results changing :) Still in think i need to do C++ because in case a have over 1 millon combinations. Only C++ will save me. Could you at least give me a hint on: " I find really complicated to set the matrix before hand in C++ when the number of elements in the set (N) and the number of subsets change (K)."

Comment: @user20650 Very elegant. I'll add to the answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @donpresente How big is your dataset? How many rows and columns?

Comment: @nicola hello. Is 40 columns, 20 Rows. But the resultant one (given all different subsets sizes) is 1 billion columns. Ideally, i cut K = 4. That would make 100.000 columns. Really expensive. I would like to expand it to allow higher Ks. Thanks for any comment.